# How can I connect node.js file to my real website (not localhost)?

Tags: node.js

I am studying node.js and on the localhost I can perfectly do the below exercise but When I try to do it on my real website it fails. After hours of search, I am not sure what I am missing. Anyhelp will be really appreciated.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-type":"text/html"});
  if (req.url === "/contact") {
     var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+"/contact.html", "utf8");
     myReadStream.pipe(res);
     };
}); 
server.listen("https://mywebsite.com");
```

### More on setup

I have 2 files, one is contact.html, it's simple html page with "hello world". And the other file is myExpress.js file which contains above code and nothing else. When I do the above exercise on localhost, I am changing server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1") and it works perfectly, but I do it on my website it doesnt work. I am using filezilla for loading files.

Comment: Please, provide more details on your setup.

Comment: I have 2 files, one is contact.html, it's simple html page with "hello world".  And the other file is myExpress.js file which contains above code and nothing else. When I do the above exercise on localhost, I am changing server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1") and it works perfectly, but I do it on my website it doesnt work. I am using filezilla for loading files.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the failure? Share the error and output that you see on the terminal when you run the command.

Comment: on the terminal it works fine, I am changing the above code to server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1") and it works perfectly. However, I have a website and I want put some node.js files in it for practice. And when I put the code above, it doesnt open "contact.html" page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is extremely broad - but, I will mention few high-level steps to take in order to run your script for real Internet traffic.

1. You need a server that faces the real Internet. It should be capable of running node.js. This can be rented from a hosting provider.
2. You need a domain name. You can obtain one from a Domain Registrar. Then you need to point your domain to your server via DNS settings.
3. You need to place your script in the server (hoping it faces the Internet properly) and listen to port 80.

Comment: I found my website IP address and also 2 nameservers numbers. Do you say I should use website ip address such as     server.listen(80, "145.244.148.41 ")    ?

Comment: No. Listen to 80 is enough, The reason you get 404 is that the traffic does not reach your node script.

Comment: you are right. It wasnt enough. I tried 80 and 443 and they didnt work. Any advice about what to see?

Answer (score 1):

Your port needs to be different in your server.listen. Change it to the one provided by your hoster - please provide some more info.

Example:

```
server.listen(3000) Listens on port 3000 on localhost
server.listen(process.env.PORT) Listens to the port - can be used for a hoster like heroku
```

Comment: I have hosting service from hostinger company. The website is this: https://eumaps.org So, when I write "eumaps.org/contact", browser window displays a 404 error

Answer (score 1):

HTTP, and HTTPS server are different protocols, so you need [extra steps](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/) to create it.

Also `server.listen` accepts [address and port](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server), not protocol.

And finally: **exposing raw Node app on production isn't a good idea** (e.g. closing connections, queue manage). Recommend way is using some reverse proxy in Nginx/Apache and some monitors e.g. `pm2` / `forever`, or more advanced: PusshionPassenger

Comment: Thank you very  much for http and https difference warning. I checked the link you shared, I will work on it